# Making sure a scrollview and view always have the same height

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view on top of the main view and then a view within the scrollView. The view within the scroll view has non-scrollable text view that adjusts based off of the number of characters that are stored on the backend. With the current configuration, the height of the view is set to a specific value (700) and that works a majority of the time but whenever the textView is bigger than the average, some of the text is automatically cut off because the scroll view isn't scrolling down far enough.

**How can I set it up to where a scroll view's height adjusts based off of the content within the view?**

Comment: Does your scroll view contain any other views as well? Or just the text view?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can achieve it assuming you only have a textView in scrollView. Otherwise it can be slightly modified to cater other cases. But you will get the idea:

- Disable scroll for text View
- Set the constraints for scroll view for e.g leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints from super view.
- Add a view to scrollview and add set it's leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints to 0.
- Now add the textView to this view and set it's leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints to 0.
- Give textView a width constraint of equal to super view i.e Scroll View.
- Now whenever the textView's height is changed i.e when text is updated. ScrollView will adjust accordingly.

Comment: Disable UITextView's scrolling and pin it to its parent. AutoLayout will automatically calculate its height. There is no need for manual calculation.